# Configuring MathJax in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax, restructuredtext

I am using restructured text and Sphinx to create content for a class.  The content is hosted on readthedocs (an example is [here](https://feathercm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/potentiostat/opamp.html)).

Below is an image of one portion of that site that I would like to improve:

> [image]

By adding the following to my `conf.py` file, I can get some improvement:

```
mathjax3_config = {
    'chtml' : {
        'mtextInheritFont' : 'true',
    }
}
```

> [image]

Is it possible to adjust the MathJax configuration so that numbers and units rendered with MathJax (250 uA in this case) appear identical to (or closely match) text not rendered in MathJax (0.250 mA in this case)?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand about "how to implement this configuration in the conf.py configuration file"? For changing styles, and assuming that MathJax provides an editable style sheet or an option to override default styles, then you would edit that to your desire.

Comment: @StevePiercy I am not sure of the syntax.  What do I need to put into conf.py in order to enforce a fixed font size, for example?  Your second sentence hits the mark: I have no idea if MathJax provides an editable style sheet because I have been unable to find a decent sample/howto and the docs are not specific enough for me.

Comment: The docs for MathJax provide several configuration options. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html Also I was incorrect about a style sheet, as MathJax renders an SVG file. For font support, see: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html

Comment: @StevePiercy in that second link, it states that MJ 3 only provides one font.  It does not look like I can change the weight of that font.  Would you agree or am I missing something?

Comment: "MathJax 3 will support these fonts in a future version." So I guess you will have to be patient, use v2, or contribute to the project to make it happen.